# Debian 10 Odoo 17 apt install odoo

Tags: debian, software-installation, python

I'm trying to install Odoo 17 on Debian 10. However, its giving me `invalid syntax`.

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/sql.py", line 65
    def __new__(cls, code: (str | SQL) = "", /, *args, **kwargs):
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/translate.py", line 1153
    res_id: ImdInfo((tmp := module_xml_name.split('.', 1))[1], model_name, res_id, tmp[0])
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

dpkg: error processing package odoo (--configure):
 installed odoo package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 odoo
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**I did install python3.10 and did update-alternatives**

```shellsession
$ sudo update-alternatives --config python3
There is only one alternative in link group python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3): /usr/local/bin/python3.10
Nothing to configure.

$ sudo update-alternatives --config python
There is only one alternative in link group python (providing /usr/bin/python): /usr/local/bin/python3.10
Nothing to configure.

$ python -V
Python 3.10.0

$ python3 -V
Python 3.10.0
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: The walrus operator was introduced in python 3.8 . Debian 10 provides python 3.7. So somehow I guess this code was not run with python 3.10 but 3.7.

Comment: Thank you @A.B. Do you know any reason why Python 3.10 is not running?